# Drawing and labeling asymptotes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do I label the asymptotes for the rational function y=(x+1)/(x-1)? I copied the code `\draw[dashed,latex-latex] ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,1}}) -- ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,0}})` from another post. I looked in the manual for this coding. The only "thing" that I got from the manual is that "axis description cs" is some description of the "coordinate system (cs)" and that {1,1} refers to the upper right hand corner of some box.  I think "|-" instructs TikZ to draw a perpendicular line.

I do not know how to modify the code to have TikZ draw the horizontal asymptote y=1. How do I put the labels "x=1" at the bottom arrowhead and "y=1" at the left arrowhead?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={-3}
]
/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[samples=250,domain=-15:15] {(x+2)/(x-1)};
\draw[dashed,shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex,latex-latex] ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,1}}) -- ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,0}});
\draw [fill=white] (-3,0.25) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[left]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip0.25in


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={-1},ytick=\empty
]
/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[samples=251,domain=-14:16] {(x+1)/(x-1)};
\draw[dashed,shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex,latex-latex] ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,1}}) -- ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,0}});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `node` to put `x=1` and `y=1`. Further, to draw a horizontal line at `y=1`, you can use `\addplot`: like

```
\addplot[samples=200,dashed,latex-latex,domain=-17:17] {1}node[above,pos=0]{$y=1$};
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
%\usepackage{tikz}      %% These are all not needed
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={-3},
    every axis y label/.style=
         {at={(ticklabel cs:1.02,-12pt)},rotate=0,anchor=west},
    every axis x label/.style={
         at={(xticklabel cs:1.02,-8pt)},anchor=south},
]
/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[samples=250,domain=-15:15] {(x+2)/(x-1)};
\draw[dashed,shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex,latex-latex] ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,1}}) -- ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,0}})node[right,pos=0.95]{$x=1$};
\draw [fill=white] (-3,0.25) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[left]{};
\addplot[samples=200,dashed,latex-latex,domain=-17:17] {1}node[above,pos=0]{$y=1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip0.25in


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={-1},ytick=\empty,
    every axis y label/.style=
         {at={(ticklabel cs:1.02,0pt)},rotate=0,},
    every axis x label/.style={
         at={(xticklabel cs:1.02,-8pt)},anchor=south},
]
/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[samples=251,domain=-14:16] {(x+1)/(x-1)};
\draw[dashed,shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex,latex-latex] ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,1}}) -- ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,0}})node[right,pos=0.95]{$x=1$};
\addplot[samples=200,dashed,latex-latex,domain=-17:17] {1}node[above,pos=0]{$y=1$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost the graph that I want. I added the command `rotate=90` to the option for the node labeling the vertical line x=1. This label is printed over the vertical line - near the bottom arrowhead. How do I move it rightward? I know that `P |- Q` instructs TikZ to account for the point at the intersection of the vertical line through P and the horizontal line through Q. In drawing the vertical line, I guess P is `{1,0}`. Why isn't this ordered pair in parentheses? What is the point Q? What is `{axis description cs:1,1}`? Why not use the code `\draw (1,0) |- (1,1) -- (1,0) |- (1,-1)`?

Comment: I have one other question.  In my original code, you added `every axis y label/.style={at=(ticklabel cs:1.02,-12pt)},rotate=0,anchor=west` to the options for the axes. And you have one for the x-axis.  Please describe the syntax to me. Do you have to have "rotate=0"?  I would like the "x" slightly below the right arrowhead of the x-axis and the "y" slightly to the right of the y-axis. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: @user143462 That is too many questions and I have only one answer. Refer `pgfplots` manual, search for those keywords and read. BTW, keep `pgfmanual` also open.

Comment: Wait.  You edited my code with `every axis y label/.style={at=(ticklabel cs:1.02,-12pt)},rotate=0,anchor=west`. You must have the opinion that this would be nicer.  Why do you think it is nicer?  Why do you have "rotate=0"?

Comment: @user143462 I just wanted the `x` and `y` not overlapping with the arrow head. And `rotate=0` was there just to show you how to rotate `y` in case if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `(c1 |- c2)` instructs TikZ to use the coordinate at the intersection of a vertical line through `c1` and a horizontal line through `c2`. In other words: Start from `c1` and go up or down (in y direction) until you are next to `c2`. This is the point you specify.

Analogously `(c1 -| c2)` intersects a horizontal line through `c1` and a vertical line through `c2`.

This is explained in more detail in the PGF manual (not PGFplots manual) in section 13.3 Coordinates at Intersections.